# Are we doing it right?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation

I just came across [this blog post](http://michael.richter.name/blogs/why-i-no-longer-contribute-to-stackoverflow) by Michael T. Richter; he talks about why he stopped contributing to SO community and system. While I don't agree with him completely, my thoughts are in line with a comment on that same blog:

> I think the problem is "playing the game". If it bugs you, don't do
>   it. I contribute all over the web in various forums, not for points or
>   prestige (I have nothing to prove to anybody), but because, after
>   decades in IT, I want to give back something of the kind help and
>   amazing mentoring I have received. So, do it because it is right and
>   not for any gaming incentive. As for a vengeful community, the fact is
>   there will be a cross section of humanity posting and responding to
>   ANY Web Site that allows that. If you aren't bothered about whether
>   you acquire points or not, then you really won't care whether they
>   "vote you down" or not. I use Stack Overflow occasionally and have
>   found it helpful, although I have not contributed to that particular
>   site. You skill and knowledge belongs to you and it is up to you what
>   you do with it, but I bet there are SOME people who were very grateful
>   for your contribution. That's what really matters.

However I do believe that the questions that he raised have some content, isn't there anything that we can do to improve our reputation system so that it is more meaningful?

For example, if someone visits my profile today will think, since I have got most reputation from [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android), that I must be an Android programmer, which I certainly am not. I haven't done a single line of coding for Android in last 2+ years.

What could be the improvements, if you think they are needed at all?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242447/what-is-the-reaction-of-se-team-on-why-i-no-longer-contribute-to-stackoverflow

Comment: Downvotes would have been better if discussed...

Comment: @royhowie thanks for the link.. that clarifies everything.. and downvotes that these questions get explains Michael's points as well.

Comment: I'm going to have to agree with the person who said, "Meh". There's enough people complaining about the rep  system on Meta; I don't see a reason to go offsite to read complaints about rep.

Answer (score 17):

> isn't their any thing we can do to improve our reputation system so that it is more meaningful ?

Sure. Tons of things. To the extent that this is a game, there are endless ways to tweak the rules to change the reward structure.

But that's missing the point.

Keeping score is a bit of fun, and for new users it's a useful tool for controlling access to potentially-dangerous tools... But it's hardly the *point* of all this. When you find a question that matches a problem you're trying to solve, find a well-written answer that explains the solution, and waste just a little bit less of your time sifting through old newsgroups as a result... Do you really care what number was next to the names of those authors?

If participating here for 7 years has taught me anything, it's that these divisions we make, these labels we give ourselves... They're pretty meaningless. The best programmers I've seen here aren't "C# Programmers" or "Android Programmers"; they're smart people who've put a tremendous amount of time into learning various things and sharing what they've learned with others. They might work with neither of these platforms or both of them, they might put "programmer" on their business cards or they might put "engineer" or "physicist" or "student". They're here to teach what they know and learn what they don't; their profiles reflect what they've done and what they aspire to.

Point is, if you want to fixate on skill labels, go cultivate endorsements on LinkedIn. If you want to trade the knowledge of your craft, then *do that* and stop worrying about numbers and labels.

#### See also: [Visualisation of Stack Overflow Tag relationships](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122900/visualisation-of-stack-overflow-tag-relationships)